# Wrap 32 bit dll for 64 bit operating system

Tags: dll, com

One of our websites uses the payment gateway HSBC CPI which requires a DLL to be registered (using regsvr32.exe), this DLL is then used inside an asp.net website. The problem is that the DLL is a 32-bit DLL and so it will not register with the the Windows 2008 operating system.

Is there a way we can wrap this 32 bit dll in a C#/.net project so that it's methods are exposed and can be registerd with the OS?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [wrap 32 bit dll for 64 bit operating system to work with regsvr32.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768336/wrap-32-bit-dll-for-64-bit-operating-system-to-work-with-regsvr32-exe)