# Project can't recognize dll in x64 machine

Tags: c#, dllregistration

I need to create a Custom Download Manager, because I don't want the Internet Explorer to fire de Default File Download Dialog.
Then, I got this example to do: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18935/The-most-complete-C-Webbrowser-wrapper-control

I've downloaded the example code and tried to run it.  after registering the DLL the program didn't recognize. The whole problem is the x64 and x86 bits thing. I work on a x64 bits machine, and it doesn't work

Then I got this post: [wrap 32 bit dll for 64 bit operating system to work with regsvr32.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768336/wrap-32-bit-dll-for-64-bit-operating-system-to-work-with-regsvr32-exe)
and tried the solutions, but the same exception was still there.

Exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in csExWB.dll

Additional information: Access denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I really need your help, and don't know what else to do. This download manager is vital to my project.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Run your command prompt as administrator and try again.

Comment: DLLs that you download from a web site will have an extra data stream in them that says that they came from an untrusted source.  Right-click the file and click Unblock.  After you checked that you can trust it of course.